# Best method to develop/preview a website with PHP, CSS, and MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, development-environment

When developing a website that will ultimately be located on a remote server, what is the best method to code and test?

Examples of what I mean:

*- Keep it local on your computer and access the files from there. Should I install the libraries and database software (MySQL) on my computer or have the file connect to the remote server.*

*- Update files on the server and refresh the browser to view changes, etc.*

*- ???*

The system I'm coding is using HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, and MySQL databases. May be utilizing cron jobs, too. The PHP is mainly used for $_SESSION and querying the MySQL databases (will have multiple databases). The remote server is running Ubuntu Linux.

Not sure what most developers do to code and check their sites. I am currently stuck on a Windows 7 environment due to work restrictions, but suggestions for OS X and Linux are much appreciated since I do work on those, too.

Please don't say to "develop on a separate server or development machine" since I do not have the budget or time for that.

Thanks!

Comment: best is so relative. what's best for you? you should know that.

Comment: I'd like to know your and other developers' setups when coding and testing. Best method for you?

Comment: Don't do all your development on the production server. If you ever make changes to any of your code, you'll want to have the opportunity to test it before your visitors see it live.

Comment: we create test.customers.site on the server develop on that then copy. doing it on the same server has the advantage of all the settings\configurations  being the same.

Answer (score 5):

You typically develop on a local machine that has all the required parts. A WAMP/LAMP/MAMP package is a popular choice, since it bundles all the required parts into an easily installable package. If you require a very specific setup which is hard to recreate on a desktop workstation, using a virtual machine is a good choice too. You then typically want to also run it on a test server which is as close to the production server as possible in every aspect to catch system and configuration specific problems early on.

Answer (score 3):

Being stuck in a Windows world usually isn't a huge problem. It is more of a problem getting all the development tools/stack installed and at the same versions as your production server. If you were on Linux or OSX, you would be much closer to your production environment. Apache and PHP are pretty much already there on both of those OS's.

But anyway, setting up a development machine that mirrors your production environment is the best approach. And, if you have enough RAM and CPU, a virtual server on your development machine using VirtualBox, VMWare, etc is a great way to go.

Best of luck!

Comment: My virtual machine's home directory is mounted as a network drive. It feels like working local, but I still have access to database connectivity when I refresh the page.  This is an ideal dev environment, no matter what database/language you choose.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends, if you are the only person doing development, there is no issue with testing on your local box. If you're developing with multiple people, you will want to test your changes on your local box, but have a 'staging' environment. This 'staging' environment is best if it is a replica of your production environment. That way there *should* be no discrepancies between your staging and production environments.

Cheers.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that I will be the only developer.

So I should install MySQL, PHP, etc on my local box and develop and test from there? Are there any big differences between the Win7 and Ubuntu Linux environments that would affect this? Thanks.

Comment: Very much so... Some PHP methods act differently on Windows than they do on Linux.  If you plan on putting your app in a Linux environment, then you should test on a Linux machine. If you plan on putting the app in Windows, test on Windows.